# How would you describe someone as being completely alone?

Tags: english-to-latin-translation, grammar-choice

If I wanted a very succinct way to say some person or thing was completely alone, how would I say this in Classical Latin? For example, if someone was drifting far out in the void of space where they were completely and utterly alone.

My first thought was something like *omnino solum*, but I wasn't sure if that would make sense without *est* or another verb to conjugate.

Comment: Some more context might help this question. When it comes to saying *completely alone*, your translation seems good, but context will determine the gender and number of *solus*, and whether or not *esse* should be present.

Comment: For context, I'm imagine a celestial body which is utterly alone in the way that something in deep space can be utterly alone. The nearest _anything_ would be so far away as to basically not exist to the celestial body itself.